# Spotlight now treating bash scripts as 'Document' instead of 'unix executable'

Tags: macos, bash, osx-el-capitan, spotlight

I have a directory of bash scripts I use frequently, and I tend to launch these via Alfred

Alfred in turn relies on Spotlight to index scripts, and assign them a meta content type of 'public.unix-executable'

Since upgrading from Mavericks to El Capitan, Spotlight was treating SOME of these scripts as 'public.data' and Kind=Document
This means they can no longer be launched from Alfred

```
$ mdls pull_repo1

..
kMDItemContentType             = "public.data"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
..
kMDItemKind                    = "Document"
```

Having reindexed Spotlight from scratch, it is now treating ALL of these scripts as public.data

Can anyone give me some insight as to why this has changed in recent OSX, and are there any solutions to fix it?

Comment: anyone want to explain why my question is being voted down? Its a perfectly valid question, and is also relevant for SuperUser.

Comment: Right click one, Get Info. Change 'Open with' to your preferred app, & a Change all... button will appear below. Might need a reboot &/or reindex before Spotlight catches up

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks, but the issue Im facing is different. OSX already knows my scripts are executable, and should open in iTerm when launched. The problem is Spotlight is assigning them a generic meta type of public.data. This was not behavior in Mavericks, where they were correctly assigned 'public.unix-executable' in Spotlights index

Comment: Ah, I see - a bit above my pay-grade, sorry, but I wonder if it's something [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) could deal with. Might be worth a look. On my machine, public.data is set to open with TextEdit, public.unix-executable with Terminal [I've never had any need to change those myself]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, although not an ideal one

After renaming all my bash scripts to have a .sh extension, Spotlight starts indexing them as kMDItemContentType = 'public.shell-script'

This at least means it can be picked up by Alfred